# Upload a file in a window pop-up using protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am using ubuntu.
While creating a connection, I need to upload a SSL certificate. When I click upload button, a Window Explorer window gets opened with only Open & Cancel Option. there is no text field to enter the path manually. We can only brose to a location and then open it. How can we achieve the save using javascript, selenium or protractor.

Comment: could you share your html and the logic you tried and also the error

Comment: Sorry, I cannot share the HTML. I tried blw code: 
var file = 'location/rootCA.pem';
            var pathToFile = path.resolve(file);
            log.debug(pathToFile);
            browser.sleep(1000);
            element(by.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Browse')]")).click();
            file_input = element(by.xpath("//input[@type='file']"));
            browser.executeScript('arguments[0].style = ""; arguments[0].style.display = "none";', file_input);
            file_input.sendKeys(pathToFile);
I am getting error as "Failed: invalid argument: File not found: location/rootCA.pem"